# Presentations, automorphisms and natural homomorphisms.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

[image: Image 1]

Exercise 2.2.2 is

[image: Image 2]

Canonical in "canonical homomorphism" is synonymous to natural. I look for a normal subgroup of $A$. Let $B$ be the set of all $\alpha\in A$ that fix $R$ elementwise. Then $B$ is a subgroup of $A$. Let $\alpha\in A$ and $f\in R$. Then $f(\alpha^{-1}\beta \alpha)=(f\alpha^{-1})\beta \alpha=(f\alpha^{-1})\alpha=f$ because $f\alpha^{-1}\in R$. Therefore $\alpha^{-1}\beta\alpha\in B$ and $B$ is normal in $A$. This is all I could get. Also, suppose $\theta:A\to A/N$ is a natural homomorphism. Then $\alpha\theta=\alpha N$. What is the meaning of $\alpha N\in$ Aut $G$?

Comment: Another author miswriting "outer automorphism" for "non-inner automorphism"...

Comment: @YCor Unfortunately many authors define "outer automorphism" to mean "non-inner automorphism", so this usage is not going to go away. We  just have to live with the fact that the elements of the outer automorphism group are not outer automorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

“Canonical” here also means that it does not depend on a particular description of the group, but only on its properties (compare for example the isomorphism between a finite dimensional vector space and its dual relative a particular basis, and the isomorphism with the double dual which is “coordinate free”).

Here, if $\alpha\in A$, then $\alpha$ maps $R$ to $R$. Therefore, since $G=F/R$, you can apply $\alpha$ to $G$ by $\alpha(gR) = \alpha(g)R$. You want to show that this is well-defined and gives an automorphism of $G$. This gives you the “canonical map” from $A$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: $\alpha (gR)=\alpha(g)R$ if $\alpha\in A$ because $\alpha$ is a homomorphism and $\alpha$ fixes $R$. Let $\alpha\in A$, $\bar \alpha:F/R\to F/R, \bar \alpha(fR)=\alpha(f)R$. I already proved that $\bar \alpha$ is a well defined automorphism.

Comment: Let $\theta:A\to$ Aut$(F/R), \theta(\alpha)=\bar\alpha$. Then $\theta$ is a homomorphism as I now prove. I have to show $\theta(\alpha\beta)=\theta(\alpha)\theta(\beta)$ or $\overline{\alpha\beta}=\bar\alpha\bar\beta$. $(\bar\alpha\bar\beta)(fR)=\bar\alpha(\beta(f)R)=\alpha(\beta(f))R= (\alpha\beta)(f)R=\overline{\alpha\beta}(fR)$. But I can't see why the homomorphism $\theta$ is a natural homomorphism. Could you explain?

Comment: @sff91: Because it is obtained by composing with the canonical projection. It is the obvious map. If you are working with some kind of technical meaning for “natural homomorphism”, then I do not know what that is and I doubt the original authors do, either.

Comment: If $N$ is normal in $G$, then the natural homomorphism with respect to $N$ is $g\mapsto gN$. Who is $N$ here?

Comment: @stf91:That’s what you are doing: you are composing $\alpha$ with $\pi\colon F\to (F/R)$.But you aren’t giving me a definition of what it means to be a “natural homomorphism”, you are just giving me an example. And if that is meant to be the definition, then that is not what the authors meant by “canonical”.

Comment: @stf91: That is, your error would lie in misinterpreting what the authors meant.

Comment: I included the author's definition in the answer box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103359/discussion-between-stf91-and-arturo-magidin).

Comment: @stf91: Sorry, I don’t like chat.

Comment: Is it possible to prove that $\theta$ is a surjection?